# Quorum privateFor not working with truffle-hd-wallet-provider

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, truffle-migration, quorum, truffle-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a contract private to one node in the Quourm 7-nodes example. The migrate works as expected when deployed normally with truffle, but ignores the `privateFor` part and deploys a public contract when used with `truffle-hdwallet-provider`. Are there any changes I can make to make the HDWalletProvider work?

2_deploy_contract.js

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
    // Pass 42 to the contract as the first constructor parameter
    deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, 42, { privateFor: ['ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc='] })
};
```

truffle.js

**Works:**

```
development: {
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 22000,
  network_id: "*",
  gasPrice: 0,
  gas: 4500000
}
```

**Fails (Deploys a public contract instead of a private one):**

```
quorum: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, 'http://localhost:22000'),
  network_id: "*",
  gas: 4500000,
  gasPrice: 0
}
```

The consensus I am using is IBFT, if that is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated:
Since Quorum v2.2.1, we now support remote signing for raw (read signed) private transactions. The API is explained in several places, but a great starting point is Quorum.js hosted here: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum.js/

Original: answered Sep 10 '18 at 18:54
At the moment, Quorum does not support sending signed / raw txns that are private -- only public ones. The simple explanation is that Quorum client (geth) will pass open data / value into txn manager (ie, constellation) on its own and when you send a signed txn, client does not have the keys needed to run it through constellation.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you tell if there is any chance of enabling remote signing in future releases?

Comment: Its likely that we will provide some kind of a custom bridge between an ethereum/quorum account and txn manager in Quorum that will allow for signing with own keys, but its a feature that we're only beginning to look at.